# Setting time in rails 2.3.8

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In some cases, I need to set start time and end time
start time is

```
Time.now.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
```

how can i set the end time after 15 minutes in the same format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this.

```
15.minutes.from_now.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
```

It won't be *exactly* 15 minutes, but close enough. If you need to be exact, do this:

```
# set times
start_time = Time.now
end_time = start_time + 15.minutes

# print times with formatting
start_time.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
end_time.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
```

Comment: thanks it works with me, I thought it could be in one line :)

Comment: @AbdallahSabriHussein It can be: `end_time = (start_time = Time.now) + 15.minutes`